# Vector smash protection is enabled

Tags: c#, winforms, sharepoint-2013

I am using a Windows Forms in my Console Application, When I am trying to execute the Application it showing "vector smash protection is enabled", can any got the same error.

Comment: please, put examples of your code

Comment: Looks like an error message related to a browser plugin like Java or Flash.

Comment: I am authenticating a share point site with CSOM,
ClientContext authContext = AuthenticationClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(clientContext, clientContext.Url);if (authContext == null)
                                      {
                                       //doing something
                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          break;
                                      }

Comment: Code is working fine but need to remove that error message